# dart extend string type for type checking

Tags: types, dart

I'm using Dart, and would like to take advantage of static type checking, by (sort of) extending the String class (I know you can't).  
Say I have:

```dart
 void putInfo(String PersonName,String GroupName){
```

but of course I could accidentally call it incorrectly with

```dart
 putInfo("grade2","Fred Bloggs");
```

Is it possible to define types such as "Personname" and "Groupname" in order 
to have

```dart
void putInfo(Personname name,Groupname group){
```

to catch such errors? And of course that could apply to ints too (width-int vs height-int), dates etc.
Thanks in advance 
cheers
Steve

Answer (score 5):

This is very easy for example in Go but in Dart the only thing you can do is to create a new class.

This can hurt performance badly if you have many such classes and use them a lot.

You can't implement several operators bacause only some of them can have custom implementations.

In overall I would discourage doing it in Dart.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say just thanks (er, I think), but thanks for this anyway, and for previous help/advice. Always appreciated. Steve

Answer (score 3):

You can't extend String the way you want to, but for your purposes you shouldn't need to.

You can use named parameters to differentiate between arguments of the same type:

```dart
void putInfo({String personName, String groupName})
```

And then call it:

```dart
putInfo(personName: 'Fred Bloggs', groupName: 'grade2')
```

One downside of this approach is that named parameters are optional so now `putInfo` can be called without any arguments. Another problem is that this is just a helpful hint and doesn't stop someone from calling `putInfo` with the wrong arguments (`personName: 'grade2`).

A better approach might to be to perform some validation on the arguments:

```dart
void putInfo(String personName, String groupName) {
  assert(personName.contains(' '));
  assert(!groupName.contains(' '));
  // More asserts validating that your arguments are correct 
}
```

You could also combine the two approaches, using named parameters for hinting, and then asserts to catch the method being called with the wrong arguments.

Comment: Note that the first downside is not true any more: you can now specify a parameter as being `required`, making sure it is defined.